# Making files writable recursively

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make every file writable under certain folders using this

> for /d /r . %%d in (nbproject) do @if exist "%%d" dir "%%d" /S | attrib -R /S /D  "%%d"

when inside a folder

> dir "%%d" /S | attrib -R

works perfectly fine. But when runing from a batch script, it is unable to do things right. Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use nested loops like this:  Just change the folder names to the folders of your choosing.

```
@echo off
for /D /R %%D in (nbproject Folder2 Folder3) do if exist "%%~fD" (
    pushd "%%~fD"
    for /R %%F in (*) do if exist "%%~fF" attrib -R "%%~fF" /D
    popd
)
```

One liner:

```
for /D /R %%D in (nbproject Folder2 Folder3) do @if exist "%%~fD" @cd /D "%%~fD" && for /R %%F in (*) do @if exist "%%~fF" attrib -R "%%~fF" /D
```

Let us also break down your first line of code for reasons where it can fail.

1. You are piping the output of `dir` into `attrib` and using the `d` variable. Only one is needed. Use the `&` symbol if using the `d` variable with `attrib` else remove the `d` variable.
2. Use the `/b` option with the `dir` command, especially when piping its output.
3. There is no need for the `.` in the for command. The current directory is assumed when not specified.
4. When quoting a loop variable use the tilde `~` to remove an existing surrounding quotations so that double quotes does not occur.
5. The `/S` option is not needed with `attrib` when using it in `dir`.

Example:

```
for /d /r %%d in (nbproject) do @if exist "%%~d" dir "%%~d" /B /S | attrib -R /D
```

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation but this makes all the files writeable, in all the folders in the same hierarchy level of nbproject. Tried some variations but couldnt get it done.

Comment: @BasitAnwer  I fixed my code to only search the directory in question.  However, the code that of yours that I fixed works just fine for me.  All you have to do is add each folder name to the space delimited list within the first for loops parenthases.

Comment: I'm sorry but the code that you fixed didnt work ... after trying out some i did manage to get it work ==== 
for /d /r . %%d in (nbproject) do @if exist "%%~d" dir "%%d" /S | attrib -R "%%~d"\*.* /S /D

Comment: Your updated code works perfectly, my for loop was very crude i think, using yours :)

Comment: Getting following error when tried the one liner:

**%%D was unexpected at this time.**

Comment: @domino_katrino the one liner is still using batch variable syntax.  If you want to use the one liner on the command line you have to change the `%%`s to `%`.  using the example: `for /d /r %D in (nbproject) do @if exist "%~D" dir "%~D" /B /S | attrib -R /D`